# Sql group by query with combine data

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Hi I have one requirement. I have below data in my table.

```
ID      REASON                     FLIGHT_KEY_ID           FLIGHT_NO                        
1709    abcddf                     0201_03/02/2016_MCT_BOM  201                     
1704    Jump Seats                 0201_03/02/2016_MCT_BOM  201                     
1706    Others                     0201_03/02/2016_MCT_BOM  201                     
1717    Last minute immigration    0225_28/04/2016_MCT_COK  225                     
1716    Last minute immigration    0225_28/04/2016_MCT_COK  225                     
1705    Last minute immigration    0225_28/04/2016_MCT_COK  225
```

Result should be

```
REASON                        FLIGHT_KEY_ID           FLIGHT_NO 
abcddf,Jump Seats,Jump Seats  0201_03/02/2016_MCT_BOM 201
Last minute immigration       0225_28/04/2016_MCT_COK 225
```

May i know is this possible? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: which `rdbms`?? `Oracle/mssql/mysql...`??

Comment: Thank you. Oracle

Comment: why does results list jump seats twice should one of those be other and last minute immigration is listed once... so you expect distinct reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listagg may not be available in your version.  Earlier versions of Oracle offered wm_concat as an undocumented feature. (use at your own risk and note it's not on the upgrade path (doesn't exist in 12c))

```
SELECT 
  wm_Concat(distinct reason) reason,
  FLIGHT_KEY_ID,
  FLIGHT_NO
FROM my_table
GROUP BY FLIGHT_KEY_ID, FLIGHT_NO
```

Ask Tom:
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9529613900346315631

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`LISTAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)

Note : `ListAgg` only available from oracle version 11g; for older versions refer `xQbert` answer;

Try;

```
select 
  LISTAGG(reason, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FLIGHT_NO) reason,
  FLIGHT_KEY_ID,
  FLIGHT_NO
from my_table
group by FLIGHT_KEY_ID, FLIGHT_NO
```

If you want only `distinct` `reasons`  then;

```
select 
  LISTAGG(reason, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FLIGHT_NO) reason,
  FLIGHT_KEY_ID,
  FLIGHT_NO
from (
    select 
      distinct reason,
      FLIGHT_KEY_ID,
      FLIGHT_NO
    from my_table    
)
group by FLIGHT_KEY_ID, FLIGHT_NO
```

Comment: Thank you. I got "LISTAGG": invalid identifier.

Comment: Oracle version you are using?? `listagg` only available from `Oracle11g`..

Comment: May need a distinct in the list agg given that the 2nd flight isn't repeated in the expected results.